# Combining table values in one output in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables: one called `tweets` and one called `references`. `tweets` consists out of the rows `tweet_id` and `classified` amongst others. `references` consists out of the rows `tweet_id` and `class_id`.

The row `tweet_id` in the table `references` only consists out of a fraction of the total `tweet_id`s in the table `tweets`.

What I would like to do is combine these tables in such a way that the eventual table shows the rows `r.tweet_id`, `t.classified` and `r.class_id`.

I've come up with this query, but for some reason it shows zero rows of output. In reality however, there are about 900 rows in `r.tweet_id` which all exist in `t.tweet_id`.

```
SELECT 't.tweet_id', 't.classified', 'r.tweet_id', 'r.class_id'
FROM `tweets` t, `references` r
WHERE 'r.tweet_id' = 't.tweet_id'
```

Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong and how I should change my script in order to get the desired outcome?

Comment: remove single quotes from your column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql uses backticks `` ` `` to [escape schema object names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html) (columns, tables, databases) and apostrophes `'` and quotes `"` to [escape strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) so you are comparing string `r.tweet_id` with string `t.tweed_id` in your condition (which is supposed to be false), do:

```
SELECT t.tweet_id, t.classified, r.tweet_id, r.class_id
FROM tweets AS t
INNER JOIN `references` AS r ON r.tweet_id = t.tweet_id
```

Note that you have to just escape word `references` because it's [reserved word in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and you can omit other backticks.

Also if you also want to display rows like `1, 2, NULL, NULL` (tweets that weren't classified) you can use [`LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp);if you allow multiple classifications per one tweet, some [*GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) may get handy.

*BTW: [PostgreSQL uses](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html) `"` for schema object names and `'` for strings.*

Comment: The table name `references` got to be escaped, because `references` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html).